# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_listId" for model "Task"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, api

My Application is working if I use a link such http://localhost:4200/lists/5fcaab9a37b7a09f7c8ea32b, however, when I try to access http://localhost:4200/lists the connection of the server breaks with the error below. Any thoughts?

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_listId" for model "Task"
> at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4358:21)
> at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4450:15)
> at C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\app.js:95:8
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at param (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
> at param (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
> at Function.process_params (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
> at next (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\app.js:24:5
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at trim_prefix (C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
> at C:\Users\camil\taskManager\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7 {
> messageFormat: undefined,
> stringValue: '"undefined"',
> kind: 'ObjectId',
> value: 'undefined',
> path: '_listId',
> reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
> at new ObjectID (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
> at castObjectId (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
> at ObjectId.cast (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:267:12)
> at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1075:12)
> at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1510:15)
> at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1500:15)
> at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1477:20)
> at cast (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:331:32)
> at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4759:12)
> at model.Query.Query._castConditions (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1841:10)
> at model.Query. (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1868:8)
> at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _find] (C:\Users\camil\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
> at C:\Users\camil\node_modules\kareem\index.js:369:33
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:75:11)
> }

app.js

```
      const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { mongoose } = require('./db/mongoose');
// Load in the mongoose models
const { List, Task } = require('./db/models');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


/* MIDDLEWARE  */
// Load middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//CORS HEADERS MIDDLEWARE
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token, x-refresh-token, _id");

    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
        'x-access-token, x-refresh-token'
    );

    next();
});

/**
 * GET /lists
 * Purpose: Get all lists
 */
app.get('/lists', (req, res) =>{
    List.find({}).then((lists) => {
        res.send(lists);        
    });
})

/**
 * POST /lists
 * Purpose: Create a list
 */
app.post('/lists', (req, res) => {
    // We want to create a new list and return the new list document back to the user (which includes the id)
    // The list information (fields) will be passed in via the JSON request body
    let title = req.body.title;

    let newList = new List({
        title,
        
    });
    newList.save().then((listDoc) => {
        // the full list document is returned (incl. id)
        res.send(listDoc);
    })
});

/**
 * PATCH /lists/:id
 * Purpose: Update a specified list
 */
app.patch('/lists/:id', (req, res) => {
    // We want to update the specified list (list document with id in the URL) with the new values specified in the JSON body of the request
    List.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id}, {
        $set: req.body
    }).then(() => {
        res.send({message: 'Updated Succesfully'});
    });
});

/**
 * DELETE /lists/:id
 * Purpose: Delete a list
 */
app.delete('/lists/:id', (req, res) => {
    // We want to delete the specified list (document with id in the URL)
    List.findOneAndRemove({
        _id: req.params.id
    }).then((removedListDoc) => {
        res.send(removedListDoc);

        // delete all the tasks that are in the deleted list
        //deleteTasksFromList(removedListDoc._id);
    })
});


/**
 * GET /lists/:listId/tasks
 * Purpose: Get all tasks in a specific list
 */
app.get('/lists/:listId/tasks', (req, res) => {
    // We want to return all tasks that belong to a specific list (specified by listId)
    Task.find({
        _listId: req.params.listId
    }).then((tasks) => {
        res.send(tasks);
    })
});

/**
 * GET /lists/:listId/tasks/:taskID
 * Purpose: Get all tasks in a specific list
 */
app.get('/lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId', (req, res) => {
    // We want to return all tasks that belong to a specific list (specified by listId)
    Task.findOne({
        _id: req.params.taskId,
        _listId: req.params.listId
    }).then((task) => {
        res.send(task);
    })
});


/**
 * POST /lists/:listId/tasks
 * Purpose: Create a new task in a specific list
 * http://localhost:3000/lists/5fc3f7b5e4e0ce9394085d4d/tasks
 */
app.post('/lists/:listId/tasks', (req, res) => {
    // We want to create a new task in a list specified by listId

          let newTask = new Task({
                title: req.body.title,
                _listId: req.params.listId

            });
            newTask.save().then((newTaskDoc) => {
                res.send(newTaskDoc);
            })
    })

/**
 * PATCH /lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId
 * Purpose: Update an existing task
 * http://localhost:3000/lists/5fc3f7b5e4e0ce9394085d4d/tasks/5fc3f877acc303780820db3c
 */
app.patch('/lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId', (req, res) => {
    // We want to update an existing task (specified by taskId)

            Task.findOneAndUpdate({
                _id: req.params.taskId,
                _listId: req.params.listId
            }, {
                    $set: req.body
                }
            ).then(() => {
                res.send({message: 'Updated Succesfully'});
            })
});

/**
 * DELETE /lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId
 * Purpose: Delete a task
 * http://localhost:3000/lists/5fc3f7b5e4e0ce9394085d4d/tasks/5fc3f877acc303780820db3c
 */
app.delete('/lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId', (req, res) => {

     Task.findOneAndRemove({
                _id: req.params.taskId,
                _listId: req.params.listId
            }).then((removedTaskDoc) => {
                res.send(removedTaskDoc);
            })
        });



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");    
})
```

list.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        trim: true
    }
})

const List = mongoose.model('List', ListSchema);

module.exports = { List }
```

app-routing.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NewListComponent } from './pages/new-list/new-list.component';
import { TaskViewComponent } from './pages/task-view/task-view.component';
import { NewTaskComponent } from './pages/new-task/new-task.component';
import { EditListComponent } from './pages/edit-list/edit-list.component';
import { EditTaskComponent } from './pages/edit-task/edit-task.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/lists', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'new-list', component: NewListComponent},
  {path: 'edit-list/:listId', component: EditListComponent},
  {path: 'lists', component: TaskViewComponent },
  {path: 'lists/:listId', component: TaskViewComponent },
  {path: 'lists/:listId/new-task', component: NewTaskComponent },
  {path: 'lists/:listId/edit-task/:taskId', component: EditTaskComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),BrowserModule,CommonModule],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

task.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebRequestService } from './web-request.service';
import { Task } from './models/task.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {
  

  constructor(private webReqService: WebRequestService) { }


  getLists() {
    return this.webReqService.get('lists');
  }

 (...)
}
```

web-request-service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class WebRequestService {
    
      readonly ROOT_URL;
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
      }
    
      get(uri: string) {
        return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
      }
    
      post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
        return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
      }
    
      patch(uri: string, payload: Object) {
        return this.http.patch(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
      }
    
      delete(uri: string) {
        return this.http.delete(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
      }
    }

task-view.component.html

    <div class="sidebar has-background-white">
      <h1 class="title has-text-primary">
        Lists
      </h1>

      <div class="list-menu">
        <a class="list-menu-item" *ngFor="let list of lists" [routerLink]="['/lists', list._id]" routerLinkActive="is-active">
          <p> {{list.title}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>


      <button class="button is-primary has-text-white" routerLink="/new-list">+ New List</button>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please show us the rest of your app.js - especially your app.get('/lists', ...) and app.get('/lists:id', ...) functions. Without it, nobody can help you without guessing :)

Comment: @CKE Sorry about that! It is updated. Thank you so much. Let me know if anything else is needed.